# excel IF formula Error, "You've entered too many arguments"

Tags: excel, if-statement, formulas

Can someone help with this?   It says, "You've entered too many arguments for this function", but works if I remove two lines.

```
=IF(IF(AND(J7<>"",IFERROR(MATCH(J$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(J$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(K7<>"",IFERROR(MATCH(K$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(K$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(L7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(L$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(L$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(M7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(M$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(M$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(N7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(N$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(N$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(O7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(O$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(O$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(P7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(P$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(P$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(Q7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(Q$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(Q$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(R7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(R$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(R$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(S7<>"", IFERROR(MATCH(S$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(S$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(T7<>"",IFERROR(MATCH(T$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""), IFERROR(MATCH(T$3, C7:F7, 0), ""),    
IF(AND(U7<>"",  IFERROR(MATCH(U$3, C7:F7, 0), "")<>""),IFERROR(MATCH(U$3, C7:F7, 0), ""), ""))))))))))<>"", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: If you only wnat TRUE/FALSE: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C7:F7,J$3:U$3))>0`

Comment: Maybe include a brief narrative explaining what your are trying to do and what you expect to return. There must be a better way to accomplish what you are attempting.

Comment: Excel has a built-in limit on the length formulas. You've simply hit it. This usually means that you're attempting something too complex with a formula. Perhaps VBA is the way forward?

Comment: I agree that having some kind of clue of the goal would be helpful, but if you want to make this syntactically correct, you need to add two more closing parentheses in the cluster before the last <>""

Comment: @OleThomsenBuus I didn't see where he was using Excel 2003.  Since then, the formula length limit has been 8,192 characters, and this formula is well below that.

Comment: "too many arguments error" : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428679/excel-formula-has-too-many-arguments/51448093#51448093)

Answer (score 2):

"too many arguments" means the number of "," , "(" & ")" is not right. Just double check for each if(a,b,c) and and(a,b,c) to have enough brackets, data/arguments and comma.

In your code, there is a total of 73 pieces of "(" and only 71 ")" . Thus, it is clear that some "(" or "IF(" was not closed properly. The corrected version :

```
=IF(AND(S284<>"",R284<>"",A284<>B284),INDEX(RATE, MATCH($A284,BID_NO,0), MATCH($R284,RATES,0)),  IF(AND(S284<>"'',R284="",A284<>B284),INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0)),  IF(AND(S284="",R284<>"",INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($B284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0)) <> INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0))),INDEX(RATE, MATCH($A284,BID_NO,0), MATCH($R284,RATES,0)),  IF(AND(S284="",R284="",INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($B284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0)) <> INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0))),INDEX(SHIFT_INFO, MATCH($A284,SHIFT_BID,0), MATCH(L$4,SHIFT_HEADER,0)),""))))
```

That should be sufficient.

Hope that solves.. (:

p/s: you may use notepad++ or other coding tools to help "highlighting" the brackets pair too.